# Why don't we use partial Hz?

Tags: fourier

Hertz seems to be considered a fundamental and atomic unit that we modulate or analyze.  112Hz, 113Hz, etc.  Wouldn't we have more to work with if we considered sub-Hertz granularity, e.g. 112.5Hz, 112.59Hz?  Why isn't this done (on a wide scale)?

Why don't we see carrier frequencies in communications systems like this for example?

Tagging 'fourier' because I don't know how else to tag this.

Comment: I work in the design of Atomic Clocks and we deal with fractions of Hz out to 14 decimal places and beyond!

Answer (score 3):

> Why isn't this done (on a wide scale)?

It is widely done. I have no idea why you think it isn't.

See for example a typical chart for the frequencies of musical notes: [https://pages.mtu.edu/~suits/notefreqs.html](https://pages.mtu.edu/%7Esuits/notefreqs.html) or https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Piano_key_frequencies

These all use sub 1Hz resolution. Otherwise you'd be playing terribly out of tune, especially at the low frequencies.